# Accessing $scope variable from another method from another controller/Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

below are services from where the two fields values comes , I want to combine those services and collect values in a single field

```
1. service.getMarketedPrograms = function() {
            return $http.get( archApiUrl + "program/marketed-program" ).then(function( result ) {
                return result.data;
            });
        };

2.service.getEligibility = function( params ) {
            return $http.get( maverickApiUrl + "quote/getEligibility", { params: params }).then( transformEligibility );
        };
```

Comment: What values do you want to combine ? What transformEligibility does ? Does the second call (getEligibility) need something from the first call (getMarketedPrograms) ?

Comment: What does *"collect values in a single field"* mean exactly?